# Laravel полиморфные отношения

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Непростая задача, которую я не могу решить. Никак не пойму, как устроено все это.

Есть 3 таблицы: Users, Filials, Specs

Юзеры, филиалы и специальности.

Каждый юзер закреплен за филиалом, и у каждого юзера есть специальность.

```
Таблица Users
    `id`
    `name` - имена юзеров
    `filial_id` 
    `spec_id`
```

Из этого выходит, что я могу в конкретном филиале выбрать всех юзеров.
В конкретной профессии всех юзеров .
И также наоборот.

Но у всех профессий (таблица Specs) есть уровень доступа.

```
Таблица Specs
    `id`
    `name` - название профессии
    `lvl` - уровень доступа профессии
```

Так вот у меня идет цикл перечисления всех филиалов: выводится имя филиала и юзеры с уровнем 2.

Сейчас в моделе Filials я просто обращаюсь ко всем юзерам

```
public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
```

Но мне нужны только уровня специальности 2.
Назначать каждому юзеру свой уровень не годится, должен именно быть у профессии уровень.
Как решить мне данную проблему без цикла в цикле?
Я читал, что полиморфно как-то можно, но как я не пойму.

Comment: Над расстановкой точек и запятых автор решил слишком не заморачиваться )

Comment: Ночью писал) А че замачиваться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, модели рекомендовано именовать в единственном числе: `Filial`, `User`, `Spec`.
Далее, в модели `User` надо сделать следующее:

```
public function spec()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Spec::class);
}
```

В модели `Filial`:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class)->whereHas('spec', function($q){
        // Указываем с каким уровнем доступа выбирать
        $q->where('lvl', 2);
    });
}
```

---

UPD. Ссылки на соглашение об именовании:
[официальная документация](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions), [гитхаб](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions)

Comment: лайк за упоминание о соглашении об именовании)) Желательно прилагать ссылочку на гитхаб, гле эти правила опубликованы)

Comment: @МаксимК, добавил ссылку на оффициальную документацию, где об этом сказано.

Comment: Спасибо за функцию, работает! А модели я и так указываю в единственном числе. Почитайте внимательнее, в вопросе я написал про таблицы, а не про модели)